# What's the external realm when configure WAS 855 with SAML SSO?

Tags: websphere, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am trying to configure Websphere 8.5.5 with a SAML SSO. I am following the article http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_configuresamlssopartners.html.

The step 1 was done with "Add an identity provider using metadata of the identity provider."

I got stuck at step 2c. what's the external realm should I use? I assume it's the external idp realm. But where to find the name for it?

Answer (score 0):

It is SAML issuer name. It is usually in IdP's metadata. If you do not have IdP's metadata, you can find the issuer from the "issuer" assertion in SAML.

Comment: I searched the IdP's metadata and found the below entries. Which one to use?    `<auth:ClaimType
    Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/field/issuer"
    Optional="true" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
    <auth:DisplayName>Issuer</auth:DisplayName>
    <auth:Description>The name of the certificate authority that issued
     the X.509 certificate</auth:Description>
   </auth:ClaimType>`

Comment: and this entry. `<Attribute
   Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/12/certificatecontext/field/issuer"
   NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri"
   FriendlyName="Issuer" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" />`

Comment: most IdP use "entityID" value in metadata as issuer name. Can you try that?